# contains cycles and cannot be serialized if reference tracking is disabled, json.net and webapi

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-5

I'm getting the error:

```
 Object graph for type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[Proj.Model.Prom, Proj.Model, 
 Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]' contains cycles and cannot be 
 serialized if reference tracking is disabled.
```

Reading about that, seems to be the serializer, but Json.Net claims to be the solution and I've read WebApi and Framework 4.5 has it by default. So Is it coming by default? If so, Why I'm still getting that error?

Thanks! Guillermo.

EDIT: Adding code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Spatial;

namespace Proj.Model
{
    public class Prom
    {
        public Prom()
        {
            this.Stores = new List<Store>();
            this.Branches = new List<Branch>();
            this.Products = new List<Product>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public DbGeography Location { get; set; }
        public string Latitude { get; set; }
        public string Longitude { get; set; }
        public int StateId { get; set; }
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Store> Stores { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Branch> Branches { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }

        public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
        public virtual State  State  { get; set; }

    }
}

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Proj.Model
{
    public class Category
    {
        public Category()
        {
            this.Proms = new List<Prom>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Prom> Proms { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Then running something like this returns the error

```
public IEnumerable<Category> GetList(int estadoId, string idTiposTarjetasList)
{
    var ids = "1,2,3,4".Split(',');
    var intIds = ids.Select(int.Parse);

    var Categories = Uow.Categorias.GetAllIncluding(c => c.Proms).ToList();
    foreach (var category in Categories)
    {
        var proms = category.Proms.Where(p => intIds.Contains(p.Id) && p.StateId == stateId).ToList();
        category.Proms = proms;
    }
    return Categories
}
```

Comment: do you see the same problem when you disable proxies? (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.infrastructure.dbcontextconfiguration.proxycreationenabled(v=VS.103).aspx)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By default, WebApi set the 'PreserveReferencesHandling' to None.

You can configure the Json.NET SerializerSettings in WebApiConfig.cs:

```
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling = 
    Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling.All;
```

Comment: Can you share your Proj.Model.Prom class?

Comment: Actually I don't think the exception is thrown by the Json.NET serializer at all.  It looks like this is thrown by DataContractJsonSerializer/DataContractSerializer.  Can you check to see if (1) your WebAPI is using Json.NET (i.e. config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.UseDataContractJsonSerializer is not explicitly set to true) and (2) your client code is requesting JSON.

Comment: Maggie, you opened my eyes, thank you so much!. I was preatty sure I had removed the xml formatter but as I'm working in more than one project at the time seems I did it for other. Taking a look at the header the browser was requesting xml, using Fiddler I changed the header to request json, and now it works.
BTW, Why it can't do it with XML? Is there a workaround for that?
Thank you!!!
Best Reagards. Guillermo.

Comment: BTW, the line of code:

            config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling.All;

Is a must, without it, it doesn't work. It says

 "The 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for content type 'application/json; charset=utf-8'.",
ExceptionType: "System.InvalidOperationException",

and

 "Self referencing loop detected for property 'Categoria' with type 'AmexToGo.Model.Categoria'. Path '[0].Promociones[0]'.",
ExceptionType: "Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException",

Comment: Glad that it helps!!  In response to your question of "Why it can't do it with XML?", the DataContractSerializer set the DataContract's  IsReference to false by default.  You can turn this nob on in the DataContract attribute:  [DataContract(IsReference=true)].

Comment: @MaggieYing is there a way to do adjust the datacontractserializer using fluent api instead of attributes?

Answer (score 4):

The following helped me:

```
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling.None;
```