# Serializing EF relationships in ASP NET

Tags: javascript, c#, json, entity-framework

I am trying to create a simple application in WebApi with the following classes.

`Author` and `Book`, the `Author` has the following attributes.

```
public class Author
{
    public int AuthorId{ get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Book> Books { get; set; } 
}
```

`Book` has the following attributes.

```
public class Book
{
    public int BookId{ get; set; }

    public string Title{ get; set; }

    public virtual Author Author{ get; set; } 
}
```

I have a db context that looks like this

```
public class DatabaseContext : DbContext
{
    public DatabaseContext() : base("dbCon")
    {
        Database.CreateIfNotExists();
        Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
    }

    public DbSet<Author> Authors { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Books> Books { get; set; }
}
```

In my view I am trying to display all authors and their related books. This is my `js` code.

```
function getData() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/api/Author',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            showData(data);
        }
    });
}

function showData(data) {
    var string = '';
    $.each(data, function (i, a) {
        string += '<h1>Question title: ' + a.Name + '</h1>';
        $.each(q.Books, function (j, b) {
            string += '<p>' + b.Title + '</p><br>';
        });
    });
    $('.divclass').html(res);
}
```

Controller method that returns all authors with related books.

```
public List<Author> Get()
{
    return db.Authors.Include(a => a.Books).AsNoTracking().ToList();
}
```

When I am trying to run the project I get an error in my console.

The following error says:

> Object graph for type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[WebApplication1.Models.Books, WebApplication1, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]' contains cycles and cannot be serialized if reference tracking is disabled. And the exception type is System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException.

I use code first migrations to seed the database and I know that the db is not empty. How do I fix this? And whats wrong?

Comment: What project is this? "Web.Api", "MVC"?

Comment: As it says in the beginning, It is webapi :)

Comment: Oh, sorry, please add tags also.

Comment: I dont have enough experience to choose that tag unfortunately. I am a new user :)

Comment: Check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13480760/contains-cycles-and-cannot-be-serialized-if-reference-tracking-is-disabled-json)

Comment: Thanks, but I have already tried that. Error is still there. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Hello @Chris welcome here, If you Google it, you’ll find tutorials that can explain it much better than we can in an answer here.

Comment: Google this `Object graph for type 'x' contains cycles and cannot be serialized if reference tracking is disabled` you will find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

As the error message tells you, your data model has cyclic references. Specifically, your `Book` class has a reference to the `Author` class and `Author` has a reference back to `Book`. You can break the cycle, if you don't serialize the book's author (you are coming from the author in your object tree, so this information is not lost). You can do that with the `ScriptIgnoreAttribute`:

```
public class Book
{
    public int BookId{ get; set; }

    public string Title{ get; set; }

    [ScriptIgnore]
    public virtual Author Author{ get; set; } 
}
```

Another option would be to change the JSON serialization settings, as described in [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13480760/contains-cycles-and-cannot-be-serialized-if-reference-tracking-is-disabled-json).

Answer (score 0):

Part of the problem is the Entity Framework's lazy loading, where it goes out and asks the database for the data whenever a reference property is accessed. This is handy for your own code, but JSON serialization *will* read *every* property.

So for each `Author` record, it reads the `Books` list, which you had already asked for. Then when it goes through each of those books, it hits each book's `Author` property and asks the database for the author information. Then when it goes through the properties of that `Author` it hits the `Books` property and asks the database for all the books by that author. This would repeat forever, but it's smart enough to just stop and throw that exception.

So another way to take care of this is to disable lazy loading whenever you return an Entity type. Something like this:

```
public List<Author> Get()
{
    db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
    return db.Authors.Include(a => a.Books).AsNoTracking().ToList();
}
```

This way, it only serializes the data that is *already* downloaded from the database. So in this case, when it serializes each book, it sees the `Author` property, sees that it's `null` and just moves on.